How to push back against people who use the Tanakh to justify and promote antisemitism?
It has been argued by atheists and other thinkers, namely self-hating Jew Christopher Hitchens, that the Bible/Tanakh is the biggest contributing factor to antisemitism, and it is not exactly without sense: the Tanakh does, after all, depict Jews in a negative light at many points in time and in numerous instances, is very critical towards Jews. Furthermore, since an atheist doesn't believe in G-d, they view the commandments as being created by the Jews themselves and as they perceive some of the commandments as being primitive or inhumane, they will thus associate these characteristics with those whom they think created these laws. Additionally, Christians, Muslims, Nazis, etc. alike do refer to the Tanakh in order to vilify the Jewish people.
So, what would be the best course of action to combat antisemites who use the Tanakh to justify and promote antisemitism? I would appreciate it if we could cite rabbinic wisdom in the answers.

Truth wins over falsehood. It just needs a chance. One must be willing to educate others, when given the opportunity (first making sure they know, themselves, what the Tanach is really about), to correct misunderstandings and defend from accusations. That's what the Rabbonim have done, and all we can do really, other than avoid these people. We don't do public debate because polemics (and in the past, violence) and other unfair play by the opponent can force a lose.

Speaking as a Christian, any Christian who attempts to justify any kind of hate - let’s alone hate against his Holy People - don’t know or understand the scriptures. Christians are taught that God is love and that the greatest commands are to love the LORD and to love your fellow man, even your enemies. So then, it is entirely illogical for a Christian to attempt to justify hatred for any group - through whom God brought salvation for the world. For everyone else: they are simply foolish to think that any other group of people wouldn’t have sinned in similar manners put in the same situations

The best way is to learn and teach other Jews. As a great mathematician said, you can never prove a conspiracy theory wrong. We have to focus on ourselves.

The truth of Torah wins over hateful lies. Teach them our traditions regarding each Halacha and story. If they’re willing to change their mind, they will. Otherwise, screw them; it’s not our job to fix every idiot on earth.

@RyanPierceWilliams Christians might be taught that now, after Nostra Ataete and the Second Vatican Council. But you can't disregard 19 centuries of brutality towards the Jews in the name of Jesus that occurred before 1965.

@Yehuda that’s what is in the NT scriptures and what the early church taught and believed since the inception of the Christian faith. Of course there have been plenty of corrupt people who have claimed all sorts of things in the name of Jesus and of God - even committing atrocities in his name. Yet their actions were clearly in conflict with the teachings of Christ, and thus their actions were contrary to the faith.

ר"א אומר הוי שקוד ללמוד תורה ודע מה שתשיב לאפיקורוס אמר ר' יוחנן ל"ש אלא אפיקורוס (של) עובדי כוכבים אבל אפיקורוס ישראל כ"ש דפקר טפי (Sanhedrin 38b)

@RyanPierceWilliams https://outreachjudaism.org/contrite-minister-apologizes-for-the-churchs-long-history-of-hate/ "Many Christians contend that those Christians who have persecuted the Jews were not real Christians. This response is both self-serving and preposterous. In fact, the most grievous expressions of hate against my faith and my people have come from the evangelical Christian world that has committed itself to converting the Jewish people to Christianity."

If the OP's question is about negative words of the prophets - these words were said with big pain and trepidation to seek teshuvah and good deeds of the Jewish people, not to serve as an accusation, as we clearly learn in mishna Pirkei Avot 4:5:

Rabbi Zadok said: do not make them (words of Torah) a crown for self-exaltation, nor a spade with which to dig (against others).

On the opposite, the claims of anti-semites are not genuine and are always made as means to exalt oneself, acquire leadership, mobilize their people against a convenient enemy, and also rob Jewish people of their possessions. When such people are using Tanakh, the same mishna Pirkei Avot 4:5 continues:

So too Hillel used to say, “And he that puts the crown (of Torah) to his own use shall perish.” Thus you have learned, anyone who derives worldly benefit from the words of the Torah, removes his life from the world.

The Jewish tradition views such people negatively. It is certainly important to point their true intentions. Because of how these people are using the words of Tanakh, they cannot be representing the Jewish people! Hitchens (1949-2011) was a socialist of the Marx and Trotsky brand of socialism. It is a religion with its dialectic materialist mysticism, very hostile to Jewish people, just as both Marx and Trotsky were.

Very nice answer and already has my +1. I just want to point out that Hitchen's turn-around from socialism is of significant note. I'd say he's mostly remembered for what he said and did after that change. Not sure how that impacts your answer but it might prevent criticism down the line if you either remove it or account for this change and compare his antisemitism before and after?

@RabbiKaii it is not clear aaccording to Wikipedia what was his change about. It would be wrong to present him as "classic liberal" because all of them were at the service of the marxist Frankfurt school, which only changed the definition of oppressor and oppressed as compared to Marx and Trotsky. All the movements which were supposed to increase tensions in society were coming from one source.
